# Edit a value in android Webview cookie

Tags: android, cookies, webview

I'd like to edit the default unit setting on the `WebView` page from "knots" to "km/h" by editing cookie.
I get the `WebView` cookie like this:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();            
cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(link);
```

The default cookie result is:

> ..wf_units=%7B%22temperature%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22windspeed%22%3A%22**kts**%22%2C%22wa...

And by editing manually the unit setting on the WV page from "knots" to "km/h"
the cookie result is:

> ..wf_units=%7B%22temperature%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22windspeed%22%3A%22**km**%22%2C%22wa...

I did like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
String ck ="..wf_units=%7B%22temperature%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22windspeed%22%3A%22km%22%2C%22wa...";
cookieManager.setCookie(link, ck );
}
```

But I still get "kts" in cookie, I have also tried this:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
cookie.replace("kts","km"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out like this:

```
// get cookie file in Android api 17
File cokieFile = new   File(getFilesDir().getParent()+"/app_webview/Cookies");

// get cookie file in Android api 23
File webviewCookiesChromiumFile = new File(getFilesDir().getParent()+"/databases/webviewCookiesChromium.db");
```

And then manually edit the "**kts**" value to "**km**" using a program to browse & edit .db files.

Next i put the edited cookie file into my app in the Assets folder.

Then i replace the webview generated cookie file by the one in my assets folder every time the app is lunched like this:

```
File app_webviewFile = new File(getFilesDir().getParent()+"/app_webview/");
File cokieFile = new File(getFilesDir().getParent()+"/app_webview/Cookies");
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();         
try {

     OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(cokieFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            InputStream myInput = assetManager.open("Cookies");
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myInput.close();
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Hope this can help some one other.